# Angular-Bootstrap don't show validation tooltip after form reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have an Angular form styled by Bootstrap containing a required field. After submitting and resetting the form, the HTML5 validation tooltip appears, indicating the required field:

[image: Tooltip]

I find this very inconsistent as the tooltip doesn't appear if the field is focused in an empty state in any other way.

How do I suppress the tooltip after reseting the form?

Here is a running [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a409cEIDVebg57dLsWmB?p=preview)

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="testForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="current-input">Input:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="current-input" class="form-control" ng-model="current_input" required />
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="check()">Check</button></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.check = function() {
  $scope.testForm.$setPristine();
  $scope.testForm.$setUntouched();
  $scope.last_input = $scope.current_input;
  $scope.current_input = ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add ng-submit and set your check function instead of calling the check by onclick,  because you are already specifying that the button type submit like below :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="testForm" ng-submit="check()">
```

......

```
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Check</button></span>
```

then it will work

cheers